# The mystery of the disappearing URL

Tags: android, google-sheets, android-emulator, android-webview, google-sheets-api

So I've been trying to get one of my activity to display a published google sheet webpage... and I managed to get it working on my emulator (nexus 5, API 22) but when I run the app on my phone (Samsung galaxy S7) it printed out a toast message "failed to find document. it is possible the document has been deleted"

I've tried testing with  and it works in both the emulator and the phone so I think the code serves it's purpose. I really don't understand...

here is a copy of my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSnBA-tNsQsUKOUCs8PkdADgMP2n4TFyl8JtKFkxUanIoXbcC9xuzY89Xw9oIRCL0ane3MKpZYRFrP1/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true");
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume Google is redirecting your url to another url. So can you try the below code for handling redirect urls in WebView.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Febi Mathew. I had tried something similar previous to my question which was

`private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }`

But it didn't work :(. I tried putting your code in my activity but the `mWebView` could not be resolved. Do I create local variable, create field, or create parameter (those seem to be the only choices...)

many thanks!

Comment: interestingly... i tried testing with a published google doc and it worked perfectly. I don't think it's a code issue then... a permission or layout issue maybe?